# Zend DB fetchAll(): where clause array with IN operator

Tags: php, sql, zend-db

I'm selecting records from a database using the equivalent of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE user_id IN (3, 6, 22);
```

The function calling fetchAll() has an argument that's an array of the user IDs, and this call works just fine:

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll('user_id IN (' . implode(', ', $userIds) . ')');
```

However, I would like to use an array for the where clause because there will probably be other restrictions to the query later... and I can't figure it out for the life of me. I thought it would be some variation on the following:

```
$resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll(array('user_id IN ?' => '(' . implode(', ', $userIds) . ')'));
```

But so far no dice. Can someone provide the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3);
$select->where('user_id IN (?)', $data);
```

Comment: Well, it's for fetchAll() instead of where(), but that's the ticket. I had tried 'user_id IN (?)' before but associated it with the result from implode(), not just the array directly.

Answer (score 2):

In Zend 2

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3);
$select->where('user_id', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = $this->getSql()->select();
$select->where("reports.user_id in ('3','6','22')"); 
$resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);             
//echo $select->getSqlString();die;
return $resultSet;
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.